# Force SSL on Joomla Module javasctipt links and all images served from content

Tags: .htaccess, joomla2.5

I have my site on https. The main problem is that since some of the images have http:// in their SRC tags and some modules seem to be including javascript using HTTP. How can I force all the internal and external calls to have https. I have full access on my server.

Comment: You can use a plugin to replace any instances of http with https, buy that has the potential to cause problems on any site that does not have SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your root `.htaccess` before any other rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|tiff|css|js)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: This is only going to work for assets located on the server, it will not fix the problem for assets being loaded from a remote server.

Comment: @BrentFriar: Yes that's correct and mod_rewrite is only for hosted resources.